# ContourPlot with certain contour values omitted

Tags: plotting, conditional

Suppose I want contour plot of $x^2-y^2$, for $x,y\in[0,1]$ (my actual function is more complicated). Over this interval, $x^2-y^2$ is sometimes positive and sometimes negative. Using `ContourPlot` I get all the contours, negative as well as positive.

But what if I wanted only those contours with values $\geq 0$ to show, while those contours whose value is less than zero are not displayed or (worst case) shown by the same color (say white). I doubt if this is possible at all, but any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `ContourPlot[
 ConditionalExpression[x^2 - y^2, x^2 >= y^2], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]` or `ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> (#^2 >= #2^2 &)]`?

Comment: @kglr Awesome. Why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can  use the option `RegionFunction`:

```
ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, RegionFunction -> (#^2 >= #2^2 &)]
```

[image]

Or use `ConditionalExpression`

```
ContourPlot[ConditionalExpression[x^2 - y^2, x^2 >= y^2], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 Contours -> 4]
```

[image]

Comment: does not this plot restricting the domain of the function? I understand that the OP ask for showing the contours that indicate levels $f>0$ while plotting the function over the whole domain...

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas, i agree with you. That's why i posted this as a comment and posted as answer per OP's suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this:

```
ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},Contours -> Rescale@Range[#]] & /@ {5, 10, 20}
```

[image]

or:

```
ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, Blue}, #] &), 
Contours -> Rescale@Range[#]] & /@ {5, 10, 20}
```

[image]

Even the contours can be customised, of course. In this case continuous for $f\geq 0$ and `Dashed` for $f<0$:

```
Show[{ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ContourStyle -> None], 
ContourPlot[Evaluate@((x^2 - y^2 == #) & /@ Range[-1, 1, 0.1]), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 
0, 1}, ContourStyle -> (If[#>=0, {Directive[Black]}, {Directive[Black, Dashed]}] & /@ 
  Range[-1, 1, 0.1])]}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Your answer is helpful too. Thank you very much.