# Mixing dashed and plain contours in a contourplot

Tags: plotting

Is there a way to tell *Mathematica* to use plain lines for contour lines associated with positive level values and dashed otherwise ?

Can't seem to find anything in the help documentation.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Posible duplicate: [https://mathematica.stackexchange.com](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160519/contourplot-with-certain-contour-values-omitted/160526#160526)

Comment: That is right on point. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this? :

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@((x*y == #) & /@ Range[-8, 8, 1]), {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
ContourStyle -> (If[# >= 0, {Directive[Red]}, {Directive[Blue, Dashed]}] & /@ 
Range[-8, 8, 1])]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
f[x_, y_] = x*y;

Show[
 ContourPlot[f[x, y],
  {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
  Contours -> Range[1, 8],
  ContourShading -> None,
  ContourStyle -> Red],
 ContourPlot[f[x, y],
  {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
  Contours -> Range[-8, -1],
  ContourShading -> None,
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Blue, Dashed]],
 ContourPlot[f[x, y],
  {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
  Contours -> {0},
  ContourShading -> None,
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Lighter[Gray], AbsoluteThickness[1]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: I must be missing something.  Why would this answer be downvoted?  Bob's answer also anticipates a zero contour.

Answer (score 1):

This hack-ish method relies on `ContourPlot[]` generating contours with the $z$-value being stored in a `Tooltip[]`:

```
ContourPlot[x y, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Contours -> 12, ContourShading -> None,
            ContourStyle -> {}] /. Tooltip[prims_, val_] :> 
                                   Tooltip[Prepend[prims,
                                                   Switch[Sign[val],
                                                          -1, Directive[Blue, Dashed],
                                                          0, Opacity[1/2, Gray],
                                                          1, Red]], val]
```

[image: differently-colored contours]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create two separate plots (one for positive, one for negative), and combine them:

```
Show[{ContourPlot[{Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]] == 0.5, 
    Abs[Cos[x] Cos[y]] == 0.5}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 0}, 
   ContourStyle -> Dashed], 
  ContourPlot[{Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]] == 0.5, 
    Abs[Cos[x] Cos[y]] == 0.5}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, 0, 3}]}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]