# Contour plot within upper and lower bounds

Tags: plotting, conditional

I have a mathematical function $f(p,q)=10^{-10}\frac{p^4}{q^2}$. I want to make a contour plot within the region where $10^{-3}<f(p,q)<10^{+3}$. I have tried the following three codes (one is similar to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160521/54258)), but their outputs are different. Could you suggest me a better way to draw the **contour plot** of that function?

```
ContourPlot[{If[
   10^-3 < (10^-10* (x^4)/y^2) < 10^3, (10^-10* (x^4)/y^2)]}, {x, 
  10^-3, 10^3}, {y, -1, 1}, FrameLabel -> {"p", "q"}, 
 ContourLabels -> True, PlotLegends -> Automatic]

ContourPlot[{ConditionalExpression[(10^-10* (x^4)/y^2), 
   10^-3 < (10^-10* (x^4)/y^2) < 10^3]}, {x, 10^-3, 10^3}, {y, -1, 1},
  FrameLabel -> {"p", "q"}, ContourLabels -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]

RegionPlot[{10^-3 < (10^-10* (x^4)/y^2) < 10^3}, {x, 10^-3, 
  10^3}, {y, -1, 1}, FrameLabel -> {"p", "q"}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Try the option `RegionFunction`

Comment: `RegionPlot[{10^-3 <= (10^-10*(x^4)/y^2) <= 10^3}, {x, 10^-3, 
  10^3}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 150, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
 FrameLabel -> {"p", "q"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]`

Comment: @ulrich-neumann

```
ContourPlot[(10^-10*(x^4)/y^2), {x, 1, 100}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, 10^-3 < (10^-10*(x^4)/y^2) < 10^3]]
```

But, I have found a point ```{{"57.45", "-0.07952"}}``` which is not within the region. However, at ```{{"57.45", "-0.07952"}}```, the value of the function is 0.172269.

Comment: @cvgmt

I need contour plot. Thanks.

Comment: @PoreyS I t looks like a scaling problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something happens near `y==0`...

As a workaround try

```
 Show[{ContourPlot[(10^-10*(x^4)/y^2), {x, 10^-3, 1000}, {y, 10^-3, 1},
    PlotPoints -> 100 , 
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z}, 10^-3 < (10^-10*(x^4)/y^2) < 10^3]],
  ContourPlot[(10^-10*(x^4)/y^2), {x, 10^-3, 1000}, {y, -1, -10^-3 }, 
   PlotPoints -> 100 , 
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z}, 10^-3 < (10^-10*(x^4)/y^2) < 10^3]]}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]
Hope it helps!